# Adapting @font-face with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have been working on a site for about a week now and we needed to include some none-regular fonts.
No problem there, i would just use the @font-face{} in CSS and it works like a charm. . . unless your name is Internet Explorer.

as IE only takes .eot fonts (as the only one of all the major modern browsers) i need to include a way to use the .eot format of my fonts when it is a IE browser that hits the site.

so, this is where i could use a hand.

If I use the IE conditional HTML to specify a stylesheep just for IE, how can i make sure that the browser will interpred the right @font-familiy? (assuming i am going to be useing the same font-familiy name with a different src)

```
//Using this
@font-face {
font-family: "ArdleysHand";
src: url(../Fonts/ArdleysHand.ttf) format("truetype");
}
//But would have to use this if IE
@font-face {
font-family: "ArdleysHand";
src: url(../Fonts/ArdleysHand.eot) format("truetype");
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conditional comments for stylesheet**

> Conditional comments only work in IE, and are thus excellently suited to give special instructions meant only for IE. They are
>   supported from IE 5 onwards.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css"> 
    @import 'iestyle.css'; 
  </style> 
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: but as the two @font-faces are identical, how can i make sure that IE looks at the right fontfamily correctly? Thanks in advance

Comment: use it after you have added the original css file and use the same class name. it will overwrite the class with same name

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional comments in your HTML file like:

```
 <!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie_font.css"> <![endif]-->
```

for all other browsers you can use this comment:

```
<!--[if !IE]> <link type="text/css" href="other_font.css"> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Should use <!--[if gt IE 6]>, because it applies for all IE versions, not just 6.